# Javascript Lossy PNG image compression library

Tags: javascript, json, compression

I have a (mostly) offline webapp where users can sign off with a digital signature (using this library: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)

The image size of a signature is about 50K, and is sent to the server as a base64 encoded json string.

Since this data is sent over satellite, I am looking to minimize the bandwidth used for each signature.

Is there any JavaScript library to do a lossy compression of the PNG to reduce the file size?

Comment: i don't think there is such a thing, but you can export the canvas as jpeg, or deflate the png data.

Answer (score 1):

PNG is inherently lossless.  If the destination can accept it, use a JPEG instead.

If not, you could try to decimate the image yourself, and then losslessly compress it with PNG.  You can also try the PNG-8 mode to compress to a palette of 256 or fewer colors (which might require a lossy step), which should result in a smaller file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I have something that may help.  I am assuming that the signature pad library uses the native Canvas.toDataURL function.

I looked a png saved from a canvas with the pngcheck utility and it uses RGBA - 4 bytes per pixel.  For your purposes you could use either a greyscale or palette color png that will be a much smaller size, but still lossless.

Large (2192 x 2800) greyscale PNG: 39KB

Same PNG drawn to Canvas (via DrawImage) and then saved back to an image via toDataURL: 184 KB.

Furthermore, the data inside a PNG is stored using the DEFLATE method - may libraries, like [this one](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/) take a compression level as an argument, basically trading speed for size.